# log4j hibernate jpa print login debug messages

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, log4j

I am using Tomcat6/J2ee app with Hibernate jpa libraries. I have database connection properties in database.properties due to some reason database connection URL is getting read from .prop file but not getting null for username and password.

I want to print debug messages to get debug log from hibernate jpa libarries following is my log4j.properties please let me know how can i add appends to print on the console on tomcat startup

```
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] - %m%n

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,A1

# c3p0 connection pool details
log4j.logger.com.mchange.v2=INFO    
# hibernate transactions and database activity
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO
# spring + hibernate interaction
log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.orm.jpa=DEBUG 
log4j.logger.org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager=DEBUG 
log4j.logger.org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter=DEBUG 
log4j.logger.org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean=DEBUG 
log4j.logger.org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor=DEBUG 
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

Comment: could you please tell me for log4j2 ?